# Bootstrap button group gets button height wrong

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap `btn-group` class to implement a menu. The menu uses the class `btn-large` to display large buttons. During page generation a Python script checks each button against the page that is generated. If the button represents the current page it adds an icon in front of the label. Nothing complicated:

```
{% for page in pages %}
        <a id="{{ page.name|slugify }}" class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="{{ page.url }}" >
        {% if page.name == current_page.name %}
            <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
        {% endif %}
        {{ page.name }}
        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I noticed that the button which has the icon in its label is actually rendered one pixel bigger than the other buttons in the group (check the top of the checked button in the image below). This only happens when using `btn-large`; other sizes display correctly.

[image]

The above is done with Chrome 27 on Mac OS X; Safari renders correctly while Firefox has the same problem but renders the button bigger at the bottom. Bootstrap version 2.3.1

My question: is this easily fixable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried putting max-height for you btn-large class?